# Show that Σ∪{α}|=β iff Σ|=(α→β).

Tags: logic

Prove that (Σ∪{})⊨ if and only if Σ⊨(→)

I am having a difficult time proving the (<---) direction of this question.

So far, I have:

Suppose Σ⊨(→). [Show that Σ∪{})⊨]

Let v be a tta that satisifes every member of (Σ∪{}). [Show that ¯ν()= .]

What steps should I take next?

Comment: Since $v(\alpha)=T$, what happens if $v(\beta) = F$?

Comment: @azif00 if ()= and ()=, then ¯ν((→)) = F. But in this case, how do we know that ()= to begin with?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a member of $\Sigma\cup\{\alpha\}$, so $v$ validates it by assumption.

Comment: @lemurs63 you shpuld use the Latex command \models to do this symbol : $\models$.

Also consider $\vdash$ (\vdash)

Answer (score 1):

Proof by contrapositive:

Assume that $(\Sigma \cup \{\alpha \}) \nvDash \beta $. Then, there is a structure $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathcal{A} \vDash (\Sigma \cup \{\alpha \}) $ and $\mathcal{A} \nvDash \beta$. Then, $\exists s_0 \; \: \mathcal{A} \nvDash \beta (s_0)  $. Then, $\mathcal{A} \nvDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta (s_0)  $ as $\forall s \; \mathcal{A} \vDash \alpha (s)$ , so in particular $\mathcal{A} \vDash \alpha (s_0) $. As a result, $\mathcal{A} \nvDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$. But since $\mathcal{A} \vDash \Sigma $, we get $\Sigma \nvDash \alpha \rightarrow \beta$.

The direct proof also follows in a similar way. You can try it for better understanding.